# how to generate Animation<T> in flutter

Tags: flutter

In Flutter, Some Animated Widget need `Animation<T>` property, like `Animation<Offset>` and `Animation<AlignmentGeometry>`.

I don't know this type, or how to get?

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Widgets such as `AlignTransition` are parts of the animation framework. You may not need them. What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: yep, such as AlignTransiton Widget, but i dont know how to generate Animation<Tween>, can u get some example for me?

Comment: That's a bit too broad. There are dozens of way to create one. Maybe explain what you truly want?

Comment: [This toturial](https://flutter.io/animations) should help you. its complete and will answer most of your questions dear. feel free to ask any question during reading the article.

Comment: Pulled in your screen shot, but you should rather provide such information as pure formatted/indented text.

Comment: This toturial i had seen. I still dont know Animation<Offset> where come from, but thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create animation object as animation controller and initialise animation and animation controller object in initState and also dispose in dispose method.

Follow below code and for more information visit:
https://flutter.io/tutorials/animation/

```
  Animation<Offset> animation;
 AnimationController controller;
  controller = new AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 2000));
 animation = new Tween(
  begin: new Offset(0.0,3.0),
  end: new Offset(0.0,0.0),
).animate(new CurvedAnimation(
  parent: controller,
  curve: new Interval(0.0, 0.5, curve: Curves.easeInOut),
));
```

Comment: i had seen this, but i dont know how to get Animation<Offset> type.

Comment: visit this link to get offset type animation object.https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/animation/Tween-class.html